# Working Rates Problem 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The boat hit something, which caused a hole in the boat. Water is leaking in at a consistent rate and some has already gathered when the hole is detected. At this stage, twelve men of the same skill can make the boat dry in 3 hours, while five men require ten hours. How many men are required to make the boat dry in 2 hours and how would you find the answer to this?

I thought that it would require 13 people to do it in 2 hours as if you increase the number of people by 7, the time decreases by 7 hours. So I thought increasing the number of people by 1 would decrease the time by 1. So what I did was add 1 to 12, which would decrease the time (3 hours) by 1 hour. I don't think this is the correct way to do it though...

Comment: Do all the men work equally fast?

Comment: It's stated in the problem that all men work equally as fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not good reasoning. Forget about the leak for now, and think about this. Suppose it takes 2 hours for 2 men to stuff 100 envelopes. Then I think it will be clear that it will take 1 man twice as long, i.e. 4 hours to stuff 100 envelopes ... So with your reasoning, it will take 6 hours for 0 men to stuff 100 envelopes?! Or, for that matter, 3 men will stuff all 100 envelopes in 0 hours?  And 4 men will do it in -2 hours?!

Clearly the math doesn't work out linearly like that!

OK, try this:

Let $z$ be how much water there is when they find the leak (in some kind of unit of measurement, gallons, liters, it doesn't really matter)

Let $x$ be how much water goes in per hour (same units)

let $y$ be how much water 1 man is able to remove per hour (same units)

Then we are told:

$z + 3x - 3 *12y=0$

and

$z+ 10x - 10*5y=0$

From this, you can figure out $z$ and $x$ in terms of $y$, and then you need to solve:

$z + 2x - 2*N*y=0$

with $n$ the number of men needed to finish the job in 2 hours.

Good luck!

If you still can't find it yourself, mouse over the below:

> Subtracting the first equation from the second, we get $7x=14y$, and thus $x=2y$
>
>
>  Filling that back into the first equation we get $z+6y-36y=0$ and thus $z=30y$
>
>  Filling $x=2y$ and $z=30y$ into third equation we get $30y+4y-2Ny=0$, and thus $N=17$

Comment: then what reasoning do you need to apply to the leak problem? Sorry i am just very confused

Comment: @Valerie Just added that to my Answer, without giving away the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. They helped me quite a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Bram28 has explained why your line of reasoning doesn't work.

As for the approach, it's best to create a few variables and express the problem in terms of them using equations for this kind of question.

---

Let the initial amount of water in the boat when the hole is detected be $a$.

Let the constant rate of flow of water into the boat be $b$.

Let the (constant) rate at which 1 man empties the boat of water be $c$.

Then the amount of water in the boat at any given time, $t \ge 0$ with $0$ being the time the hole was detected, with $k$ men at work is

$$W_k(t)=a + (b-kc)t$$

(assuming the number of men is proportional to the rate at which they empty the boat).

---

See if you can solve the problem from just this and if you get stuck, you can look below for hints.

---

We are given from the question:

$$W_{12}(3)=a + 3(b-12c) = 0$$

$$W_5(10)=a + 10(b-5c) = 0$$

From this, you get

$$3b - 36c = 10b - 50c$$

$$\implies b = 2c$$

Substituting back in, you get

$$a = 30c$$

Substituting again, you get

$$W_k(t)=(30 + (2-k)t)c$$

Now you are asked to find $k$ such that $W_k(2)=0$.

$$\implies (30 + 2(2-k))c=0$$

$c \neq 0$

$$\implies 30 + 4-2k=0$$

$$\implies k=17$$

Comment: wait isn't the answer 17?

Comment: @Bram28 That would be because I made a silly mistake - $a=30c$ and not $b$. My bad and thanks! ^^'

Comment: @Shuri2060 Ah, ok, I was wondering, since we effectively did the exact same thing! :)